# WPF - Change button templated text color on DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, multidatatrigger

I have a button that has a control template set (including some controltemplate triggers), and I want to change its text color upon a DataTrigger. I've read that I cannot access the TargetName ("theContent") of the template as it has its own scope, so how can I achieve this?

```
  <Button BorderThickness="0" MaxWidth="94" Height="26" Margin="1,0,0,0">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">                        
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border x:Name="theBorder" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Label x:Name="theContent" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <TextBlock Text="..." TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"></TextBlock>
                                </Label>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1A65AF"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#4d87c0"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#004b95"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{...}" Value="..."></Condition>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False"></Condition>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ad4811"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#7F7F7F" /> // does nothing
                        <Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Foreground" Value="#7F7F7F" /> // target not found
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <!--<Button.Content>
            <Label x:Name="theContent" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold">
                <TextBlock Text="..." TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"></TextBlock>
            </Label>
        </Button.Content>-->
    </Button>
```

The 2 setters that I tried and don't work are these:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#7F7F7F" /> // does nothing
<Setter TargetName="theContent" Property="Foreground" Value="#7F7F7F" /> // target not found
```

Comment: Why don't you use the button's `Foreground` property for this purpose? Template-bind the foreground of the label in the control template against the button `Foreground` property. Then you can manipulate the button foreground (=label foreground) in the button style...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your control template, you just need to use `TemplateBinding` rather than hardcoding the value to `White`.

```
<Border x:Name="theBorder" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
  <Label x:Name="theContent" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="Bold">
    <TextBlock Text="..." TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"></TextBlock>
  </Label>
</Border>
```

Doing that will defer to the button `Foreground` property. Generally, if any properties need to change in your `ControlTemplate` dynamically, you will want to use `TemplateBinding` (for example the `FontWeight` property). Now your `StyleTrigger` setter will work as expected.

Btw, `Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"` is just shorthand for

```
Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```